# Are legendary and unique weapons with same description identical?

Tags: fallout-4

There is number of weapons in the game which description matches exactly equivalent legendary versions. For example description of *Le Fusil Terribles* matches exactly *Violent Combat Shotgun*, or *Tinker Tom's Special* matches *Stalker's Hunting Rifle*.

Are they in fact the same in stats? Is name the only difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, name is the only difference.

From [Nukapedia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_weapon_effects):

> Legendary effects can provide the same effects as unique weapons; a "Relentless .44 pistol" is identical to Kellogg's pistol.

Comment: Actually im wrong on that.  I think I'm thinking of the wazer wifle from fo3

Comment: @z' It looks like it's a darker color in that picture. Maybe it's just the lighting in the screenshot.

Comment: @z' I'll roll it back unless/until we find a better example.